# Preorder traversal of a quadtree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, tree-traversal, quadtree

So I know for a binary tree the general way to preorder traverse it is like this

```
void displayPreOrder(TreeNode node)
{
    if(node != null)
    {
        displayPreorder(node.left);
        displayPreorder(node.right);
        System.out.println(node.value);
    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble trying to wrap my head around a preorder traversal of a quadtree. I've tried to find some resources, but left empty handed. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is for a **post**order traversal of a binary tree. For a quadtree, you just need to visit all children instead of just left and right.

For simplicity, I'll assume that `TreeNode` defines a method `children()` that returns an iterator or a `List` of the node's children in some well-defined order. If that's not available, just iterate through the children using whatever mechanism is available.

```
void displayPreOrder(TreeNode node)
{
    if(node != null)
    {
        // visit the root first for pre-order
        System.out.println(node.value);
        for (TreeNode child : node.children()) {
            displayPreorder(child)
        }
    }
}
```

(P.S. This works for binary trees as well, given the right iteration mechanism.)